# Where to find a list of marketplaces (NYSE,LSE) and the financial products they offer?

Tags: stock-market

**I'm looking for a list (csv/json/api...) of all marketplaces (New York Stock Exchange...) and the financial products** that are offered on those market places.

Preferrably worlwide but US and EU will be fine.
A small description of products with their fields (PHARMA, TECH, AGRO...) will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You’re aware that most products outside of equities, options, and foreign exchange (and even a large fraction of equities by firm and foreign exchange by volume) are not traded on exchanges, but over-the-counter, so the “marketplace” for those products doesn’t consist of a named entity?

Comment: A list of all equities and options available would be a good start.

Comment: Cool. I’m not posting this as an answer, because I’m only addressing the US and the reality is a bit more complicated than your question assumes (i.e., since regulation NMS, most listed equities trade across all trading venues, so a list of equities by market doesn’t make sense), but here’s the list of US equities and options exchanges: https://www.sec.gov/fast-answers/divisionsmarketregmrexchangesshtml.html

Comment: In fact I don't know if i use the good words. Probably not. The link you provided lists all the exchanges platform (or "market places") and their associated websites which is good but what I really want is a list of equities (stocks shares sold on the market places). I want to know that Apple Corp = AAPL is sold on the NASDAQ. Should I dig every website (the one of the NYSE, the one of NASDAQ...)  to get this list or is there an international list of equities and their unique id (like ISBN for books) ?  Thank for you patience anyway

Comment: For equities listed on the major exchanges you can find that here: https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx

Comment: More broadly, there do exist databases that contain the information you’re looking for (specifically, reference databases for ISIN, which is an international securities identifier, sort of like an ISBN). They’re expensive, though.

Comment: Doh. Thank you. With your help I found some interesting pointers https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17315/where-can-i-get-historical-fundamental-data-for-multiple-companies-in-a-single-c